# Why does navigator.getCurrentPosition (function (position) { } ) not be called from a click event on a google maps marker

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I have a google map with some markers.

I have added an event listener for the 'click' event on a specific marker. 
When the user click the marker I want to get a direction from my current position to the position af the marker.

For that I use the following code:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            gLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            gLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
        });
    }
```

The two line code to update my globale variables gLatitude and gLongitude are never executed.

Are there some limitations in calling navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition from a google.maps.Marker event?

If so, can anyone give suggestions on how to read the current position when clicking a marker on google maps?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What browser are you using?

Comment: No errors or messages in the browser. I use Google Chrome for developmen

Comment: mmhhh...can you test the `geolocation service` outside the marker and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. It works. I have other functions that uses navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and it works. That's why I was thinking that maybe google maps somehow prevent you from calling geolocation?

Comment: No, there is nothing in their documentation that suggest so. Let me understand this right; you want to run the `HTML5 Geolocation` after the Map and Marker are loaded?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When the user click on the marker, I want to get the current location.

Comment: `HTML5 Geolocation` can compromise privacy, so that position should not be made available unless the user approves it. This means that `Geolocation` should be called when the user lands in your home page and accept to be geolocated. That is way before the map is loaded. You may be looking to return coordinates results when a marker is placed or clicked on a map?

Comment: The user has accepted and approved access to current location. I render the map and the marker. The idea is that the user can ask for direction to the marker when he clicks on it. But to do that I need current location. That's why I want to read it from Geolocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have explained above, `HTML5 Geolocation` may raise privacy concerns if users do not authorize access to their geographical data. However, since you want to extract the coordinates with a click event, this is what you could do to improve the snippet above:

```
var map, marker;
function initMap() {
 var sidney = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 center: sidney,
 zoom: 6
});

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: sidney,
    map: map

  });

 marker.addListener('click', function() {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log("true");

    var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lng);

    });
   }
 });
}
```

If you test this in your browser you will see a number of logs showing you the coordinates you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and your time. Could you make it work on the marker click only? I do not want to have position on every click on the map, only on the marker?

Comment: well just assign the `addListener` to the marker and not the map object; but I guess that you get the coordinates as you expected? That way when the user click on the marker you get the coords

Comment: Do you still need help with this or you are done with it?

Comment: It works now in my app. The problem was not getting the current position, but a scope problem with my map and marker. Thank you very much for your help and code snippet. It helped me identifying my problem.

Comment: Can you accept my answer please? Some rewards do not hurt my work :)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and would love to accept your answer. I have tried to click on the up arrow but a message is displayed that I have not reputation to update votes. Is there somewhere else I can accept your answer?

Comment: Ok. Found it...  I think. :-)